# Java POJO representing HTML controls?

Tags: java, html, controls, pojo

Well, it may be a idiot idea... But we need DropDownList.java to wrap all data of a "List employees" dropdown list. The object is populated at server side and used by JSP and javascript (json) for rendering view. Just something like org.apache.struts2.components.Select but in POJO format.

We already created our own classes but if there is some good framework or lib that made that kind of stuff, we would willingly use it.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

There is [Java HTML Generator](http://artho.com/webtools/java/index.shtml) but the API is a bit clumsy. If you can, write the HTML generator in Groovy using the [Builder API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Builders).

Groovy code is compiled to normal class files which just needs the groovy.jar on the classpath.

Comment: Wow, heard about Java HTML Generator for first time. Very interesting. I am reading it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Google's Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) (GWT)?

This is probably one the cleanest solutions for rendering browser content I have seen. POJO's are "compiled" into native JScript and HTML by GWT. Concerns about browser compatability are dealt with by GWT.

After completing a large project using GWT I can testify that this is very much a production ready tool, both scalable and responsive.

Comment: Oh yeah. I like GWT too (after a small project). But our project is on the midway. Unable to change to GWT. Anyway, it seems to me that they are not POJO and cannot be used outside the box